# Jquery Validate Conditional Phone US

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-validate

Using the Jquery Validate Plugin with the phoneUS method.

The following code (striped down a little) works everywhere except of course IE the bane of my developer existence.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
        phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
        return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
            phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
    }, "");

    jQuery("#myform").validate({
            rules: {
            EmailF: {
                required: true,
                email: true
        },

         PhoneF:{
            required: "#mycheck:checked",
            phoneUS: true

        },

            },

            messages: {
                 EmailF: " "
            },
 });
});

    </script>
```

Basically I have a checkbox (#mycheck) and when checked the PhoneF field needs to be validated. If not checked it doesn't need to be validated.

As mentioned working FF, Chrome, Safari and even on the IPhone but IE can't get around the condition.

I've tried several different methods of turning the required field into a function to check if the checkbox is checked by IE doesn't play nice.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of IE is giving you the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned which version of Explorer is giving you trouble, but you can try one or more of the following to get your dependency method working...

**1)**  Older versions of Explorer will choke on trailing commas.  Remove the two trailing commas from your code just to be safe.

```
rules: {
    EmailF: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    PhoneF: {
        required: "#mycheck:checked",
        phoneUS: true
    }, // <-- REMOVE this comma
},
messages: {
    EmailF: " "
}, // <-- REMOVE this comma
```

**2)**  This code is another way to write your dependency rule...

```
PhoneF: {
    required: function(element) {
        return jQuery('#mycheck').is(':checked');
    },
    phoneUS: true
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/TBCPM/**

**3)**  Using the `depends` sub-rule is also a valid method...

```
PhoneF: {
    required: {
        depends: function(element) {
            return jQuery('#mycheck').is(':checked');
        }
    },
    phoneUS: true
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/UutTk/**

Comment: It is IE9 giving the issues. I will try it out with the depends sub rule. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: So yeah still not working for me on IE9 with either method. Perhaps it is another issue completely. I am using the Zurb Foundation custom forms with this. It creates custom checkboxes using spans. Might be something funny there that IE can't handle. I will give this a test just using a straight form. Thanks again for taking the time and for the fiddle examples.

Comment: @user892670, Trailing commas would not be an issue in IE 9.  There is nothing about the jQuery Validate code that would only be giving you problems in IE 9.  Try my jsFiddle DEMOs and see.

Answer (score 0):

If I can suggest..

adding "(|x\d{1,4})" to the match for extensions ex: 1(999) 999-9999 x123

should end like -?\d{4}(|x\d{1,4})$/